# Продление домена

Tags: домен

Сегодня кончается срок моего .ru домена на сайте reg.ru, стоимость продления - 899 рублей. У меня сейчас вообще нет денег, домен ОЧЕНЬ нужен.
Чтобы купить его снова за 199 рублей, надо подождать 1 месяц, когда домен будет неактивен и он еще будет принадлежать мне, а ждать не вариант. Может можно его как-то удалить быстро, чтобы зарегистрировать заново? Или быстро перенести в регистратор, где продление дешевле? Домен зарегистрирован на несуществующий паспорт.

Comment: Не продлите его сегодня за 899, через месяц вы его у reg.ru уже сможете купить минимум за несколько тысяч ;) https://habrahabr.ru/post/338206/#comment_10552000

Comment: продлите на месяц, а за это время подыщите варианты переноса к другому регистратору... обычно при переходе регистраторы делают скидки...

Comment: @Alex А как это "продлить домен на месяц"? Такое вообще возможно? Обычно минимальный период регистрации/пролонгации - год

Comment: весь смысл заработка на regru это продлевать за дорого

Answer (score 1):

Если домен зарегистрирован на несуществующий паспорт, то, скорее всего, вы не сможете перенести его к другому регистратору (разве что у reg.ru упрощены условия). Процесс переноса не очень быстрый.
Месяц - это джентльменское условие регистрации, этот период не сокращают.
Что же касается варианта с удалением и повторной регистрацией, то всё зависит от привлекательности доменного имени. Если имя интересное, или домен был раскручен за время существования, то вряд ли вы его повторно зарегистрируете. Такие домены регистрируются спустя доли секунды после окончания срока действия.